# Meaning of a German idiomatic phrase in mathematics

Tags: idiom, german-to-english, mathematics

Softball question here....

Does

> Dabei sollen *G<sub>1</sub>* und *G<sub>2</sub>* einen Winkel einschließen, der zum vollen Winkel 2π in einem irrationalen Verhältnis steht.

mean the following?

> Thereby, (lines) *G<sub>1</sub>* and *G<sub>2</sub>* should subtend/intersect in an angle that is an irrational multiple of 2π

The focus of my inquiry is the *der zum vollen Winkel 2π in einem irrationalen Verhältnis steht*.  Does this precisely mean *irrational multiple of 2π*?

Comment: I wasn't sure if "in einem irrationalen Verhaeltnis steht" meant more than the individual words did.

Answer (score 6):

Essentially, it does mean exactly this, but it is worded a bit differently: The ratio (*Verhältnis*) of that angle to the full angle (2π) is supposed to be irrational.

Comment: Oh, excellent.  Mathematically, those mean the exact same thing.